# loading dynamic image from local source

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have saved some images to local path of pc and saved the file name to db. Now i want to load all the image from db and show to html page using java script and thymemleaf. Browser says not allowed to load local resources , So i made a servlet in spring boot. But it does not showing image.

`Servlet`

```
@WebServlet("/admin/imgServlet")
public class AdminImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String urlImage = request.getParameter("admin");
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        ServletOutputStream out;
        out = response.getOutputStream();
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Public/Documents/" + urlImage);

        BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
        BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
        int ch = 0;
        while ((ch = bin.read()) != -1) {
            bout.write(ch);
        }

        bin.close();
        fin.close();
        bout.close();
        out.close();
    }
}

@Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean adminImageServlet() {
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.register(AdminImageServlet.class);
        dispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet, "/admin/imgServlet");
        servletRegistrationBean.setName("imgServlet");
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }
```

Java script for loading image

```
'<img src=imgServlet?admin='+articles.bannerImg+'  class="img-responsive" />'
```

error i'm getting  `imgServlet:1 GET http://localhost/techtalks/admin/imgServlet?admin=pyjc4x0B.jpeg 404 (Not Found)`

And i also want to load image from local resources to thymeleaf html page

`model.addAttribute("localImg", "E:\\picz\\assasins.jpg");` spring controller will pass the Model like this and it will pass the image to respective file to html page like this.

`<img th:src="@{${localImg}}"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Servlet code works for me. I am able to get the image successfully.

I presume the problem could be most likely the file name. Please input the file name as below (i.e. without 'e' in jpeg).

It should work if the file is present in the local path that you are referring.

```
pyjc4x0B.jpg
```